# Database diagram tool understanding Servicestack/Ormlite

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is there a *database diagram tool*
understanding Servicestack/Ormlite 
like the
*Entity Framework Power Tool*
for ASP.NET Entity Framework ?

Answer (score 0):

[OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) is a code-first POCO so your C# classes are the single source of truth. If you wanted to visualize your POCOs you could use something like [VS.NET's class diagram](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyxd8c85.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) tool which will let you visually layout your classes.

OrmLite's project page includes an example of a class diagram to quickly view its API at a glance, e.g:

[image]

I believe VS.NET also lets you [create Database diagrams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171978.aspx) to visualize your RDBMS tables, although I've never used it.